# How to turn off converting empty strings to null in Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a form with some textfields. It is valid to enter nothing into the fields, but I want to get the empty String then. Wicket automatically converts empty strings to `null`. I found out that `FormComponent`s have a flag called `FLAG_CONVERT_EMPTY_INPUT_STRING_TO_NULL`. I think this flag is responsible for my issue.

But how can I override this flag? Are there global Wicket-settings for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you found this flag you might have noticed this method

```
public final FormComponent<T> setConvertEmptyInputStringToNull(boolean flag)
```

that's used to set the flag to whatever boolean value desired...
It's part of the AbstractTextComponent parent-class to TextField. For further information, check the [JavaDocs](https://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/AbstractTextComponent.html#setConvertEmptyInputStringToNull%28boolean%29)